# Sum of counts on multiple tables MSSQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query.

```
SELECT  (
    SELECT
        COUNT (fibre_circuit.data_id) 
    FROM fibre_circuit
        INNER JOIN bus_std_iptv
            ON  bus_std_iptv.d_parent_id = fibre_circuit.data_id
    where fibre_circuit.data_id = 778
) AS Count1,
(
    SELECT
        COUNT (fibre_circuit.data_id)
    FROM fibre_circuit
        INNER JOIN bus_pre_iptv
            ON bus_pre_iptv.d_parent_id = fibre_circuit.data_id
    where fibre_circuit.data_id = 778
) AS Count2,
(
    SELECT
        COUNT (fibre_circuit.data_id)
    FROM
        fibre_circuit
            INNER JOIN iptv
                ON iptv.d_parent_id = fibre_circuit.data_id
    where fibre_circuit.data_id = 778
) AS Count3,
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        fibre_circuit.data_id
    FROM fibre_circuit
        INNER JOIN bus_std_iptv
            ON bus_std_iptv.d_parent_id = fibre_circuit.data_id
    where fibre_circuit.data_id = 778
)
AS circuit
```

The result is:

```
Count 1 | Count 2 | Count 3 | Circuit

3       | 1       | 1       | 778
```

I need to SUM Count1 + Count2 + Count3 to just receive:

```
Total | Circuit

5     | 778
```

Anyone could help on elaborating the right query to get desired result?

Thanks in advance,

Miguel

Comment: Replace the `,` between count1, count2 and count3 with a `+` and rename count3 total.  or cross join to the sums instead of select subqueries and then add up the totals..

Comment: Thank you xQbert. It worked!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's a primary key on those three tables you're joining fibre_circuit to, then you could do something like this:

```
select
    fc.data_id as [Circuit],
    count(distinct piptv.[whatever primary key there is here]) + 
    count(distinct iptv.[whatever primary key there is here]) +
    count(distinct siptv.[whatever primary key there is here]) as [Tota]
from fibre_circuit fc
    left outer join bus_pre_iptv piptv
        on fc.data_id = piptv.d_parent_id
    left outer join iptv
        on fc.data_id = iptv.d_parent_id
    left outer join bus_std_iptv siptv
        on fc.data_id = siptv.d_parent_id
where fc.data_id = 778
group by fc.data_id
```

Comment: It gives me 9 Total instead of 5.

Comment: @MiguelBérniz then could you provide example table structures and example data?  it's hard to know what's going on without it

Comment: fibre_circuit is parent table for fibre circuits. Key field is fibre_circuit.data_idThose fibre circuits can have different

Comment: fibre_circuit is parent table for fibre circuits. Key field is fibre_circuit.data_id Those fibre circuits can have none, one or many related registers in any of the three child tables called iptv, bus_std_iptv and bus_pre_iptv, In these tables, key field is *iptv.data_id and relationship field is d_parent_id I am trying to know, given a fibre_circuit.data_id, how many child registers exist aggregated in the three childs table. Ideally, I would need to start the query from any of the three child tables, but that is too complex for me.

Comment: @MiguelBérniz try running it with the count(distinct ...) that I just added

Comment: It works now, thank you very much. Much simple structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT  (  
    SELECT
    COUNT (fibre_circuit.data_id)   
    FROM
    fibre_circuit  
      INNER JOIN
    bus_std_iptv  
    ON
    bus_std_iptv.d_parent_id = fibre_circuit.data_id  
    where
    fibre_circuit.data_id = 778
    )  +  
    (SELECT
    COUNT (fibre_circuit.data_id)  
    FROM
    fibre_circuit  
    INNER JOIN
    bus_pre_iptv  
    ON
    bus_pre_iptv.d_parent_id = fibre_circuit.data_id  
    where
    fibre_circuit.data_id = 778
    ) +  
    (
    SELECT
    COUNT (fibre_circuit.data_id)  
    FROM
    fibre_circuit  
    INNER JOIN
    iptv  
    ON
    iptv.d_parent_id = fibre_circuit.data_id  
    where
    fibre_circuit.data_id = 778  
    ) AS Total,  
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT
    fibre_circuit.data_id  
    FROM
    fibre_circuit  
    INNER JOIN
    bus_std_iptv  
    ON
    bus_std_iptv.d_parent_id = fibre_circuit.data_id  
    where
    fibre_circuit.data_id = 778  
    )
    AS circuit
```